# rails routing - path issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

i've been scratching my head over this, but i keep getting this error

> No route matches {:action=>"show", :category_id=>nil,
>   :controller=>"products", :id=>nil} missing required keys:
>   [:category_id, :id]

In my simple minded logic whenever i go for category_product_path and pass in the category, i should have the list of products within that category. But i'm probably missing something. This is my view file ... where i've tried several stuff without success

```
<% @products.each do |product| %>
    <tr>
        <td><%= link_to product.name, category_product_path(@category) %></td>
        <td><%= product.category_id %></td>
        <td><%= number_to_euro(product.price) %></td>
        <td><%= product.stock %></td>
        <td><%= image_tag(product.image.thumb) %></td>
        <br>
        </tr>
<% end %>
```

This is my routes

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :categories
  resources :products
  resources :orders
end
resources :categories, only: [:index, :show] do
  resources :products, only: [:index, :show]
end
resources :orders, only: [:new, :create]
```

And what i assume to be the problem, somewhere in the controllers (not the ones in the admin folder)

```
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController    
    before_action :set_category, only: [:show]
    def index
      @categories = Category.all
    end

    def show
      @products = @category.products
    end

    private

    def set_category
      @category = Category.find(params[:id])
    end
end

class ProductsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_product, only:[:show]
    def index
        @products = Product.all
    end

    def show
    end

    private

    def set_product
      @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    end
end
```

Comment: `category_products_path(category_id: @category)` note that is `products` in plural.

Comment: But it still does not much sense to link to the index. I think what your are looking for is `link_to product.name, category_product_path(category_id: product.category, id: product)`

Comment: hey. the first one does not work, gives the same error, however the second one works like a charm. thank you. And yes it doesn't make much sense, i'm still learning. what i wanted to actually do is go to a categories page, and from there select the category of products and list them. so basically that is index in a sense... or then again it could just be a 'filter' page if you will :). Oh and i have a question, can you explain to me this part 'category_id: product.category, id: product' it's unclear, and i can't find anything in the rails documentation about paths with multiple arguments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to add both `@category` and `product` variables to your route:

```
<%= link_to product.name, category_product_path(@category, product) %>
```

--

**Update**

I don't know where you're calling your view, but if I'm right in thinking it's `categories/:category_id/products/`, then `@category` isn't being set:

```
#app/controllers/products_controller.rb
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
   def index
      @category = Category.find params[:category_id]
      @products = @category.products
   end
end
```

If you're *not* doing this, it does suggest your `@category` value is not present. To test this, manually insert a `@category` value:

```
<%= link_to product.name, category_product_path("2", product) %>
```

---

Tip: [*Multiple resource declarations*](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#defining-multiple-resources-at-the-same-time)

```
#config/routes.rb
namespace :admin do
  #needs a root
  resources :categories, :products, :orders
end
resources :categories, only: [:index, :show] do
  resources :products, only: [:index, :show]
end
resources :orders, only: [:new, :create]
```

Comment: thank you for the tip, i need to read more about this (routes) and get it together. however the solution provided leads to 'No route matches {:action=>"show", :category_id=>nil, :controller=>"products", :id=>"2"} missing required keys: [:category_id]'. And this is becoming unclear to me, zwippie posted something similar, and i got the fact that both need to be passed. but given @category doesn't work => and i assume this is the main cause, could it be that i need to define it in the products_controller ? just like it i defined the products in the categories ? this was my initial thought

Comment: yes that's it !!! ha, i guess i had the right idea, but just didn't know how to put it into practice ... thank you !!! One question however, max said something about it earlier. In a normal application, you'd rarely see a products index, usually you'd see products based on category. in this case would it be logical to go for a different name for the function/view ? like ... category_list or something ?

Comment: No, you've done it well - you'll see the url as `http://url.com/categories/1/products` which seems logical to me

Answer (score 0):

For a nested resource route, you have to pass the ids/objects of both the category and the product:

```
<%= link_to product.name, category_product_path([product.category_id, product.id]) %>
```

Comment: hmm ok, i've learned something new, i need to pass them both. however this solution brings up the error - No route matches {:action=>"show", :category_id=>[1, 2], :controller=>"products", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]